# How to highlight a certain range of text inside textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, highlight

is it possible to highlight a certain range of characters inside a text area with the use of jQuery. I have had a look and tried a few things to no avail. I am trying to highlight the start to the end of iframe code inside a textarea.

```
if ($('#textarea').val().match(/<iframe(.*?)<\/iframe>/)) {
    // code here
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:contains()` for your job. Like for example.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contains demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>

<script>
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "bold" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

wll result in

**John Resig**

George Martin

**Malcom John Sinclair**

J. Ohn

Refer the [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). The Example is from the api.jquery.com

Comment: This doesn't highlight code which is what I wanted.